# Lumen 8.2 Mix content issue with swagger asset urls - Heroku

Tags: laravel, swagger, lumen

I am using Lumen 8.2 and swagger darkaonline/swagger-lume 8.0 . All working fine on local, but when hosted, its giving error

> The site loaded over https , but requested an insecure stylesheet
> swagger assets

I have tried all solutions provided on stack overflow and other sites.

```
if(env('APP_ENV') != 'local')
{
   URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

Not working for me

Error
[image]

Comment: Please can you show the code that's loading the stylesheet.

Comment: Its a swagger, autoloading the assets files https://sudkumar.com/blogs/api-documentation-in-laravel-and-lumen-with-swagger